# Spring Statemachine and xml Configuration

Tags: spring-statemachine

i'm new on Spring Statemachine framework. It's possible using configuration on classic XML configuration file ? State, Event and action would be more clear.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, please elaborate what you are asking with use cases, sample data and examples.

Comment: in Answer 1 there is reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet but we have some github issues to track these requests, i.e. [gh78](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/78)

Comment: Thanks Janne. Are you going to develop this feature?

Comment: Hopefully at some point either by me or someone else. Problem is limited amount of time/resources etc.

Answer (score 0):

By docs i have :

`static enum States {
    STATE1, STATE2
}

static enum Events {
    EVENT1, EVENT2
}

@Configuration
@EnableStateMachine
static class Config1 extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<States, Events> {

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<States, Events> states)
            throws Exception {
        states
            .withStates()
                .initial(States.STATE1)
                .states(EnumSet.allOf(States.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<States, Events> transitions)
            throws Exception {
        transitions
            .withExternal()
                .source(States.STATE1).target(States.STATE2)
                .event(Events.EVENT1)
                .and()
            .withExternal()
                .source(States.STATE2).target(States.STATE1)
                .event(Events.EVENT2);
    }
}
@WithStateMachine
static class MyBean {

    @OnTransition(target = "STATE1")
    void toState1() {
    }

    @OnTransition(target = "STATE2")
    void toState2() {
    }
}

static class MyApp {

    @Autowired
    StateMachine<States, Events> stateMachine;

    void doSignals() {
        stateMachine.start();
        stateMachine.sendEvent(Events.EVENT1);
        stateMachine.sendEvent(Events.EVENT2);
    }`

This example use spring annotation for configuration. I would configure it by XML spring configuration files.